# Why does Eclipse not seem to be able to find swing?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Swing does not seem to exist in my Eclipse. I have now twice uninstalled and reinstalled Java, and also Eclipse from different mirrors, and yet this issue persists. I know swing is supposed to be part of the standard lilbrary, so I don't know why the program does not find it. This program:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreateABasicGUIProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Swing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

produces these error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    JFrame cannot be resolved to a type
    JFrame cannot be resolved to a type
    JFrame cannot be resolved to a variable

    at HelloWorld/com.example.helloworld.CreateABasicGUIProgram.main(CreateABasicGUIProgram.java:9)
```

ChatGPT says the reason is that the Java program can't find the JFrame class, which is part of the Swing library, and that this typically happens when the Java compiler can't locate the necessary libraries.

I've followed all the tips in ChatGPT about what to do about this, and the problem persists. I've been working on it for days.

Thank you very much for any thoughts you may have.

Comment: Which version of Java? Can you compile _any_ Java programs (for instance if your `main` had only a System.out.println`)? Which operating system?

Comment: Hi, and thank you! I'm using Java 17 on Windows 10 Pro. I've been compiling quite a lot of cool programs in Java, and println's are working fine.

Comment: I got the program to run successfully from the command prompt. It just doesn't run in Eclipse.

Comment: After working several more hours on this, ChatGPT has finally said: “It's indeed puzzling that such a common feature isn't working in your environment, despite following a plethora of steps to troubleshoot." I’ve gone through about 100 attempts of different ways to get this right. Any thoughts about what could be wrong with the Eclipse setup such that it does not recognize Swing at all would be appreciated.

Comment: I've found the solution, at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBzwSf8bEdQ. Anyone who has questions about this can reach out to me, thank hyou!

Comment: probably code is *modular*, that is, it has a `module-info.java` in the root source foler, declaring the module your code is in. If that is the case, you must add `requires java.desktop;` to that file - usually Eclipse shows a hint about that...

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it a bit more evident (and prevent being dependent on youtube):

The issue is a modular application. For some reason the `java.desktop` module has not been declared in the module-info.java file hence access is forbidden.

The solution is to add the line

```
requires java.desktop;
```

to the `module-info.java` file in the root of the project.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much -- I really appreciate your having answered this question!